# AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserver does not print all values

Tags: swift, avplayer, intervals

I am trying to use 1/50 sec interval in my AVPlayer time observer. But that does not print all values.

```
let interval = CMTimeMake(1, 50)    
AVPlayerVC.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: {(progressTime) in

  let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
  let doubleSeconds = String(format: "%.2f", seconds)
  print ("\(doubleSeconds) -")
```

This is the result:
0.00 - 
0.05 - 
0.09 - 
0.13 - 
0.21 - 
0.30 - 
0.40 - 
0.45 -
0.54 - 
0.59 - 
0.70 - 
0.75 - 
0.85 - 
0.96 - 
1.07

How can I have every 0.02 second? (0.00 - 0.02 - 0.04 - 0.06 ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserverforinterv?language=swift) states, your callback is not guaranteed to get called as frequently as you request:

> If the interval corresponds to a very short interval in real time, the player may invoke the block less frequently than requested. Even so, the player will invoke the block sufficiently often for the client to update indications of the current time appropriately in its end-user interface.

What are you trying to accomplish that you want to be notified so frequently?

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part of the documentation. I needed to compare 2 arrays to show some buttons on video. But I change the logic and now that is better. I don't need a short interval anymore.